# What happened if I don't set EPOLLOUT event and direct call write() function?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, epoll

I have EPOLLIN event for read data only. Is it ok to direct write the data without setting EPOLLOUT event?

Comment: Sure, it is not a *requirement*, but if the data can't be sent right away, the `write()` will either block the calling thread (blocking socket) or fail with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` (non-blocking socket). In the latter case, you could just call `write()` again periodically, or you could use `EPOLLOUT` to know when the socket is ready to send data before calling `write()` again.

Comment: Can I do `if (EWOULDBLOCK || EINTR ||  EAGAIN) then I retry to write` ?

Comment: You can. But in such case, if the socket is blocked for awhile (network lag, unresponsive peer, etc), you would end up in a busy loop calling `write()` over and over, wasting CPU cycles.  Better to put the calling thread to sleep waiting for `EPOLLOUT` (or have the thread go do something else for awhile and come back later) before calling `write()` again.

Answer (score 6):

When using `epoll` with level triggered notifications, you will get constant `EPOLLOUT` notifications on a socket except for those brief periods of time that the output buffer for the socket is actually full. The impact of this is that your event loop will wake up even if you have nothing to send, and there was no data to receive either.

To deal with that, you have two practical choices:

1. Disable `EPOLLOUT` until those times you actually get `EWOULDBLOCK` / `EAGAIN`. At that point, you enable `EPOLLOUT`, and disable it again once your send is complete.
2. Enable edge triggered notifications, and leave `EPOLLOUT` enabled all the time. Now, you will only get `EPOLLOUT` notifications when the system changes from a output buffer full state to non-full state. However, `EPOLLIN` is now also also edge triggered, which means you only get one `EPOLLIN` notification until you drain the input buffer.

In comments, a third option was presented to you to implement your own polling loop to deal with the sockets with full output buffers. This can be made to work, but should not be necessary, since `epoll` can tell you when it is okay to write.

Comment: what if i do EPOLLIN for listenfd only, once accepted, bring along accepted fd and spawn new thread to do recv and send and close? It won't blocked the epoll, it also work alone in the thread.

Comment: You never want to write to the accepting socket, so EPOLLIN only is fine for that socket. Generally speaking, pre-emptive thread per connection servers don't scale very well, but if the load is expected to be light, it works well and the code can be easier to understand.

Comment: I mean in psuedo coding
fd = accept(...);
new thread(fd) {
recv(fd...);
heavyProcess();
send(fd...);
close(fd);
}

So I can handle multi threaded request concurrently?

Comment: @Oktaheta My comment is the same. It doesn't scale, but if that doesn't matter, it works.

Comment: @jxh  "Enable edge triggered notifications, and leave EPOLLOUT enabled all the time" should it not be "Enable edge triggered notifications, and start with EPOLLOUT disabled. When you get EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN on write enable EPOLLOUT"

Comment: @asinix: No. With edge triggered and EPOLLOUT always enabled, the application always attempts to write. When write blocks, it only waits for notification, since EPOLLOUT is already enabled.